# linq calculated value with group by

Tags: c#, linq

Having a little trouble constructing a linq statement (C#, query syntax but I could handle method sytax). It needs to support grouping as well as a exposing a calculated property. I have a handle on each individually but can't get them to seem to work together. Any help would be appreciated.

**Data**

```
GrpField          Qty      Price
-------------     ---      -----
RED                1        10
RED                2        10
RED                1        50
BLUE               2        30
BLUE               2        50
```

Output needs to be sum of Total Price (Qty * Price) for each group

**Desired Result**

```
RED    80
BLUE  160
```

This gets me the Total Price line

```
from x in origdata
let linetotal = x.qty * x.price
select new { x.grpfield, x.qty, x.price, linetotal }
```

But I am unable to group by the new anonymous type since you can't run aggregates like sum on anonymous types. If I run the group first, I can't figure out how to work the linetotal into the mix BEFORE the aggregate sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As evidence against your *since you can't run aggregates like sum on anonymous types* statement...

```
var data = new[]
    {
        new {GrpField = "RED", Qty = 1, Price = 10},
        new {GrpField = "RED", Qty = 2, Price = 10},
        new {GrpField = "RED", Qty = 1, Price = 50},
        new {GrpField = "BLUE", Qty = 2, Price = 30},
        new {GrpField = "BLUE", Qty = 2, Price = 50},
    };

var grouped =
    from d in data
    group d by d.GrpField
    into g
    select new {Group = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(x => x.Qty * x.Price)};

foreach(var g in grouped)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", g.Group, g.Sum);
```

Comment: That statement wasn't my opinion - it was the compiler error (and in the MS documentation) if you take my original query and try to run the group by on the anon type. The trick (as evidenced by your and other answers) was to do the group by first.

Answer (score 2):

Group first, then sum the operation.

```
origdata.GroupBy(m => m.GrpField)
 .Select(group => new {
     GrpField = group.Key,
     CalculatedValue = group.Sum(m => m.qty * m.price)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
origdata.GroupBy(p=>p.GrpField)
.Select(p=> new()
{
    GrpField=p=>p.Key,
    Sum=p.Sum(q=>q.Qty*q.Price)
})
```